# when execute Agent_UnLoad() method about "java -agentpath:c:/tool.dll javaClass

Tags: java, dll, jvm, jvmti

> I just start learning `JVM TI`.
>   About the java command: *java -agentpath:../tool.dll javaClass*, I know that there is a `Agent_OnLoad()` method in `dll` and maybe it set some event `callback method`. And I know the jvm execute `Agent_OnLoad()` first and then execute `javaClass`.And the `Agent_OnUnLoad()` is also called by jvm.

---

Then the problem comes, **how the jvm know when call `Agent_OnUnLoad() method`** . At First, I think that after `javaClass` is executed jvm will calls `Agent_OnUnload()`, but then I discard this thought because at this time, maybe the `dll` is doing sth e.g. writing data to disk.

---

> So ***how jvm know it is the right time to call Agent_OnUnLoad() method?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standard mechanism defined to unload agent libraries. `Agent_OnUnload` will be called only before the VM termination, when all Shutdown hooks are completed.

Comment: but I encounter a <code>condition</code> that the <code>Agent_OnUnload</code> is called and the jvm is still running. For example, I have ATest.java,BTest.java...ZTest.java and the *execute order* maybe <code>Agent_Onload </code> *ATest.java BTest.java*... <code>Agent_OnUnload</code> ...*ZTest.java* that is to say, ***the Agent_OnUnload is called and jvm go runing ***

Comment: @cainiaofei This means some class has called `System.exit()` or `Runtime.getRuntime().halt()`